# TabContainer в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

В Nuget загрузил Ajax Control Toolset, и в коде создал TabContainer.
В разметке показывает созданный TabContainer, но при запуске созданной веб-формы ASP.NET выдает ошибку "A ScriptManager is required on the page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script Components".
Как исправить?

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" Height="150px" Width="205px">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="first" runat="server" HeaderText="Signature and Bio" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="Second" runat="server" HeaderText="Second">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте на форму контрол ScriptManager (на панели инструментов находится в группе AJAX Extensions):

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" Height="150px" Width="205px">
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)